# How to get information about youtube video using python?

Tags: python, youtube

I am creating a simple youtube video installer. How to make me get: title, time and preview of any video using Python? It's best to save them so that they can be output separately via "print()", and the preview could be downloaded as jpeg or png?

I used lxml but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the YouTube Data API to retrieve information about a video, including its title, duration, and a thumbnail image. The following Python library can be used to interact with the YouTube Data API: "google-api-python-client".
You need to have a Google developer API key to access the data.

Here is an example of how you can use the library to retrieve information about a video and print the title, duration, and thumbnail URL:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY"
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)

request = youtube.videos().list(
    part="snippet,contentDetails",
    id="video_id"
)
response = request.execute()

title = response['items'][0]['snippet']['title']
duration = response['items'][0]['contentDetails']['duration']
thumbnail_url = response['items'][0]['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url']

print("Title: ", title)
print("Duration: ", duration)
print("Thumbnail URL: ", thumbnail_url)
```

Official Documentation for the Youtube Data API can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3)